# SQL Server Management Studio - Calculating Correct Total

Tags: sql-server, sum, ssms, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a column in a SQL Server table with values like this:

```
ID      Value  Item#
-------------------
101     10     Apples
102     20     Apples
102-01  22     Apples
102-02  23     Apples
102-03  21     Apples
103     20     Apples
103-01  15     Apples
```

How to write a query to get correct total for values?

For the given example the values should only be taken for : `101`, `102-03`, `103-01`.

The correct sum should be `46`.

I tried using like and contains keywords in where clause. It did not help.
Group by and Max messes up the total.

And just using `sum(values)` gives total of everything which is wrong

Comment: How do you determine which records should be taken into account in the sum?

Comment: 101,102-03,103-01

It should take the item number but if anything has '-0' in front of it (for example 102-01) etc, then it should take its MAX value.
so only 101,102-03,103-01 should be choosed for total in the example image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to group records by the prefix of their id (the first 3 characters), and sum the value of the keep the record with the highest suffix per group (if there is more than one record).

You can use `row_number()`, then filtering and a sum:

```
select sum(value) total_value 
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by left(id, 3) order by id desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```